# How to add arp entry for an entire subnet (/16)?

Tags: arp, proxy-arp

I would like to add ARP entry for an entire subnet (`10.50.0.0/16`).

I tried : `arp -v -i p4p1 -s 10.50.0.0 MAC_OF_P4P2 netmask 255.255.0.0 pub`

But the command returns:

```
arp: SIOCSARP()
SIOCSARP: Invalid argument
```

No problem if I add one by one: `arp -v -i p4p1 -s 10.50.0.1 MAC_OF_P4P2`

Is there any way to do what I want ?

Something like: `arp -v -i p4p1 -s 10.50.0.0/16 MAC_OF_P4P2`

## **Story:**

I have 3 interfaces: `eth0`, `p4p1` and `p4p2`.

`p2p1` and `p2p2` are connected through a device but let's say like a wire.

We have multiple servers with `A.B.x.x` in the network that is connected to `Eth0`.

#### From the system, I would like to access to `A.B.x.x`:

1. Through `Eth0` directly: `ping A.B.X.X` **no problem**, it does automatically

[image]

2. Through `p2p1` -> `external device/wire`
   -> `p2p2` and then redirect to `Eth0` : `ping 10.50.X.X`

[image]

In that case, I need to create virtual IPs `10.50.0.0/16` that will be same as `A.B.0.0/16` but through the `p4p*` interfaces.

Packets need to keep `10.50.x.x` as IP source/destination, only when it reaches `eth0`, the IP will be translated to `A.B.X.X`.

Let's do it step by step.

1. I route `10.50.0.0/16` to my interface `p4p1`: `ip route add 10.50.0.0/16 dev p2p1`.

### => p4p1 doesn't know `Who has 10.50.0.152?  Tell 10.0.0.1`

#### I need to set an ARP entry to link `10.50.0.0/16` to `p4p2`.

Comment: I'm not certain what you're trying to accomplish here. What is the ultimate goal for this setup? Are you implementing some sort of loopback? Adding fake ARP entries almost certainly isn't what you're wanting.

Comment: It's complicated to explain what's the ultimate goal. I just need to assign a subnet IPs to an interface. This interface is not connected to a network but to a device.

Comment: If it's not possible, how about adding dynamically an entry when one IP is used?

Comment: If you're assigning a subnet to an interface, that sounds more like *forwarding* to me, in which case you should be using adding a route, not using ARP at all. Is this more accurate?

Comment: I edited my post. I've already added the routing rules. `10.50.x.x` is a "virtual/alias" to say go through a specific interface(p2p1). But p2p1 is lost because it doesn't know which has this IP.

Comment: I don't understand why I need forwarding, I did it already with POST/PRErouting in NAT table. My interfaces have only one ip.

Answer (score 2):

Support for proxy arp entries for networks (netmask not equal 0xffffffff) was dropped in Linux 2.2. It is replaced by automatic proxy arp setup by the kernel for all reachable hosts on other interfaces (when forwarding and proxy arp is enabled for the interface).

Reference:
https://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman7/arp.7.html

Maybe you could try the setting.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/"interface"/proxy_arp
```

The interface will check route table relate interface subnet and sending arp proxy packet.

Comment: Wow that seems nice and might be the solution. I'll accept it once I tested it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is set up a route. You question doesn't say whether this `10.50.0.0/16` subnet exists **on** the destination device, or **behind** the destination device, but it really doesn't matter. As far as your machine is concerned they are both exactly the same.

When you add a route to your routing table, what you are saying is to route all traffic for the destination subnet to the MAC address of the device with the given IP. For example, with `ip route add 10.50.0.0/16 via 1.2.3.4`, when your system needs to talk to any machine in `10.50.0.0/16` it's going to look up the MAC address for `1.2.3.4`, and send the traffic to that MAC address. **Nowhere in the outgoing packet does it have the IP address `1.2.3.4`**.

Thus your solution is simple:

```
ip route add 10.50.0.0/16 via 1.2.3.4
```

^ where `1.2.3.4` is the IP of the device owning that MAC address `00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`. If you've got multiple interfaces on the same subnet (which is likely a bad idea, but not always), you can specify the outgoing interface:

```
ip route add 10.50.0.0/16 via 1.2.3.4 dev p2p1
```

Comment: I added some diagrams. I think your solution is equivalent as what I've already done: `ip route add 10.50.0.0/16 dev p2p1`. Still the `p2p1` doesn't know who has `10.50.0.0/16` then cannot route packets properly. (Checked with `wireshark`) My problem is not routing problem but MAC/ARP problem since it does properly work if I add ARP entries manually for each 10.50.x.x.